# Restricting upload of any other file on s3 bucket except the file for which the presigned url is generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio, pre-signed-url, aws-php-sdk

I am using php to create a presigned url and send that to front-end and that uploads directly to s3 using that presigned url. I want to secure and restrict that upload.

for example I have created a presigned url for file "stack.txt" and I want the upload to fail/restrict any other file of different name being uploaded to s3 bucket.

How can I implement that ?

Comment: The same way you are doing this now. Do you have any code or can you explain why it does not work?

Comment: not sure if that's a thing - s3 is going to allow you to upload whatever you want as long as you have a policy set for the uploader. What you could do is a mix of versioning and restricting uploads to only a single IAM user or aws service.